# Clarify behaviour of "removed" JDK 8 (byte code) dependancies on JDK 11+ apps

Tags: java, java-11

I'm trying to understand how removed code removed in `JDK 11`, such as `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` will behave in a `JDK 11 JVM.`

I have a `jar` file which uses the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` class (in say, my `FooEncoder.java`) - and is complied with `JDK 8`.
I then have a `JDK 11` compiled application that imports and uses the `FooEncoder.java` class (and does invoke the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` at runtime. This works but thought it would have caused an issue on basis that `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder` was removed in `JDK 11` - and therefore there would be a `bytecode` issue at runtime for this application.

Any tips to help clarify how the `JDK 11` application (and the `JVM` view) is able to run using this `JDK 8` byte code (that again includes the `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`)

Thanks!

Comment: The run-time is backwards compatible, so a compiled jar should be fine.

Comment: If for some reason it becomes a problem, use this:  https://github.com/jenkinsci/xstream/blob/master/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/util/Base64Encoder.java

Comment: You'll get a NoClassDefFoundError or ClassNotFoundException at run-time because sun.misc.BASE64Encoder won't be found. It has always been risky to use JDK internal and undocumented APIs. Is there any reason why the code compiled to 8 cannot be changed to use java.util.Base64?

Comment: Thanks @Alan, yes I do now see those exceptions. I guess I must have had a mistake with my build, as this is the behaviour I was expecting. I was just using the Base64Encoder as an example, and I have multiple use cases / libs to consider